# Floating Theorem amsthm

Tags: floats, theorems, amsthm

I have an environment thm defined with newtheorem of amsthm, and one of my theorems has multiple small codes (lstlisting) and text in between. This theorem takes about 2/3 of a page and I would like the whole theorem to be contained within a single page.

My initial solution was to include the whole theorem within a minipage, and this was successful. The problem is that page breaks are now bad and I would like my theorem to be floating.

My first intuition was to use

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{floatingstuff}{t}{lop}
\floatname{floatingstuff}{}
```

But:

1. I fail to compile. It seems that having captions and labels for the lstlistings within my theorem breaks including it in a float.
2. I do not need additional caption or name. I hope that using floatingstuff is not going to introduce an additional caption for my whole theorem... and I really wish to use the theorem defined through newtheorem.

Therefore, I am searching for a floating environment that does almost nothing, except change where the element is positioned. And I have not yet found one, although floats are probably based on it...

If someone knows how to define such an environment, it would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT] The afterpage solution would be a great solution, but I am unable to make it work. A reduced code that does not work is the given below. Commenting either the listings or the afterpage works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{afterpage} % for '\afterpage' macro
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{def}{
    language=C++,
    mathescape,
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    literate={<-}{$\leftarrow{}$}{2},
    literate={<>}{$\ne{}$}{2},
    frame=none,
    numbers=none,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10!white},
    emphstyle={[2]\ttfamily\bfseries\color{blue!50!black}},
    emphstyle={[1]\color{orange!70!black}},
}

\lstset{style=def}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\afterpage{
\begin{thm}[$insts_P^{abs}(expr, ctx), relevant(a_{var}, \omega)$] $\ $\\\label{alg:cell:inst} 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=caml, mathescape, caption={Instantiation heuristic for cell abstraction.}, label={lst:insts:cell}]
let $insts_P^{abs}$ expr ctx =
  let $a_{var}$ = new_variable () in (* We need $a_{var}$ to be unused in expr and ctx*)
  let R = relevant $a_{var}$ ($a_{var} = expr \wedge \neg ctx$) in
  ler R' = filter (fun e -> e $\ne \top$) R in (*We remove $\top$*)
  if R = [] then [(($\bot$, expr[$\bot$]), ())] (*We need $R$ non-empty*)
  else map (fun e -> ((e, expr[e]), ())) R
  Blabla
\end{lstlisting}
Some result about this function
\bigskip 
\begin{lstlisting}[language=caml, mathescape, caption={Computation of a relevant set of cells for basic array theory.}, label={lst:relevant}]
let relevant $a_{var}$ $\omega$ =
  (*We add two parameters that we set in first position 
    to keep track of full context and visited variables*)
  relevant_impl $\omega$ [] $a_{var}$ $\omega$  
 Blabla
\end{lstlisting}
Some result about this function
\end{thm}
\clearpage}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: if you aren't using lined or boxed floats, you would be better off using the newfloat package (fewer unfortunate side effects).

Comment: you show a code fragment using `float` package and an error from the `floatrow`  package but as you haven't provided any code that shows the use fo floatrow a bit hard to answer.  It would be rather unusual to float a theorem, it could go out of sequence with non floating theorems, it may be better to simply adjust the position in the source so that you get a good page break.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had mentioned sooner that you employ `lstlisting` environments. If I had known about this, I wouldn't have posted an answer (which I've now deleted).